# wordpress shortcode return array can click able

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am new in wordpress and php.

So, i create shortcode in functions.php to get xml from url and show it in post.

This is xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<all_emp>
<emp_detail>
    <emp emp_name="john"><img>john_1.jpg</img></emp>
    <emp emp_name="john"><img>john_2.jpg</img></emp>
    <emp emp_name="john"><img>john_3.jpg</img></emp>
    <emp emp_name="marry"><img>marry_1.jpg</img></emp>
    <emp emp_name="marry"><img>marry_2.jpg</img></emp>
    <emp emp_name="david"><img>david_1.jpg</img></emp>
</emp_detail>
</all_emp>
```

This is shortcode:

```
$url = 'https://.../emp_test.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file("$url") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$names = array();   
$emps = $xml->children()->emp_detail->emp ; 
foreach($emps as $emp_detail)
{
    $source = (string)$emp_detail->attributes()->emp_name; 
    $names[]= $source; 
} 
$names = array_unique($names); 
return implode("<br />", $names);
```

This is result i get in post:

```
john
marry
david
```

Everything is ok.

Now, i want john, marry, david can click able.

And if i click "john", it will open new page and send string "john" from post to page.

I can do it in wordress?

If can, how to do that?

Thank you for reading.